# C# generic B+tree

Tags: c#, generics, b-tree

I'm implementing a B+tree using C#.

Now as i understand it, a tree node should hold a number of (order - 1) keys, and order number of pointers to records or other nodes, i.e., only the leaf nodes would hold actual pointers to records , and internal nodes would hold pointers to other nodes.

The problem I'm having with this implementation is with C# generics

the Node Class is Declared as:

```
class Node< K,V >
{
    K [] keys ;
    V [] values;
}
```

Now when i attempt to place a node into the values array as such

```
_root.Values[0] = left ; // left being of type Node<K,V>
```

I get the following Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'BTree_Library.Node' to 'V'

So, I'm trying to find a way to work around this, the other option is to change the implementation to hold one array for nodes and one for records.

So, in conclusion :

1. In C I would have used :`( void* values; )`
   I'm looking for an equivalent of that in C# .
2. While we're on the subject did I understand the B+tree structure correctly 
   in reference to nodes and records being interchangeable for the nodes pointers?

Comment: Use Lists instead of arrays - you won't be able to add items to arrays.

Comment: @Martin, that's the point of a B-tree, that each node has a constant count of keys and values, but some of them can be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your leaf nodes and your inner nodes to act differently, while still being able to refer to both of them as nodes. That describes an inheritance hierarchy:

```
abstract class Node<K, V>
{
    public K[] Keys { get; protected set; }
}

class LeafNode<K, V> : Node<K, V>
{
    public V[] Values { get; protected set; }
}

class InnerNode<K, V> : Node<K, V>
{
    public Node<K, V> Children { get; protected set; }
}
```

Another option would be to use the C# equivalent of `void*`, which is `object`, but that would mean the code is not type-safe anymore and you would have to have casts everywhere. I would not recommend doing this.

That being said, why are you creating your own B-tree? It's useful only when keeping the data on disk, not in memory. If you're doing it only to have associative array, there are classes in .Net that already implement it (like `Dictionary<K,V>` or `SortedDictionary<K,V>`) and that work perfectly fine.

Comment: 10X, that's a good idea using inheritance 
i did end up using object, ill attempt to change that now to your suggestion .
i'm doing a class project witch requires me to create my own DBMS
i want to keep the records on a csv file, but haven't gotten to that part yet , first i want to create my own B+tree ( also for my own enriching ) , i would mark your answer but i don't got the rap for it , appreciate to help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `_root.Values[0] = left` is being executed from within the class and that `Values` is a property equivalent to `values`.

If V will always be a type of `Node`, you can try something like

```
interface INode {
}

class Node<K, V> : INode where V : INode {

}
```

This will force V to derive from `BTree_Library.Node`, which will allow that line to compile without any errors.

If V will not always derive from `Node`, then I think generics might be the wrong way to tackle this.

Comment: It should be    where V :Node<K,V>

Comment: I think generics are exactly the right way here. What else would you recommend?

Comment: i found the solution i added a constraint in The Tree class And In Node Class

class Node< K,V > where V : class class BTree< K,V > where V : class

in main i declared

BTree< int,object > tree = new BTree< int,object >(3);

Comment: V isn't always a node its a node only if its in an internal node
its a record if its in a leaf node.

Comment: if V isn't always a node, then it isn't always the same type, so Generics won't be helpful, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node
{
   bool IsLeaf;
   List<TKey> Keys;
}

class InnerNode : Node
{
    List<Node> Children;
}

class LeafNode : Node
{
    List<TValue> Values;
    LeafNode Next, Prev;
}

class BPTree<TKey, TValue> 
{
    Node  Root;
}
```

Comment: `List<TKey> Keys

Comment: Where did you get the idea to prefix every line with `\``? That's not how code blocks work in Markdown. Either indent the whole block by 4 spaces (you can do this by selecting the code block and pressing Ctrl+K or clicking the code block button) or fence it with `\`\`\`` on its own line before and after the block. See [code block].

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?